# How to get disk list on VM

Tags: kvm-virtualization, centos7

I installed CentOs 7 as host after I installed a guest VM withe CentOs 7 every thing work.

I have to questions
1. How can i see the disks guest from host on the cli. Like when i run 
"virsh list --all"
2. How can I create from cli to add another disk without creating xml paragraph

Thanks

```
<domain type='kvm'>
<name>ub</name>
<uuid>e8f4117b-7fd8-49bc-a15a-5a8cae73bf4f</uuid>
<memory unit='KiB'>59660288</memory>
<currentMemory unit='KiB'>59660288</currentMemory>
<memoryBacking>
<hugepages/>
</memoryBacking>
<vcpu placement='static'>32</vcpu>
<cputune>
<vcpupin vcpu='0' cpuset='0'/>
<vcpupin vcpu='1' cpuset='1'/>
<vcpupin vcpu='2' cpuset='2'/>
<vcpupin vcpu='3' cpuset='3'/>
<vcpupin vcpu='4' cpuset='4'/>
<vcpupin vcpu='5' cpuset='5'/>
<vcpupin vcpu='6' cpuset='6'/>
<vcpupin vcpu='7' cpuset='7'/>
<vcpupin vcpu='8' cpuset='8'/>
<vcpupin vcpu='9' cpuset='9'/>
<vcpupin vcpu='10' cpuset='10'/>
<vcpupin vcpu='11' cpuset='11'/>
<vcpupin vcpu='12' cpuset='12'/>
<vcpupin vcpu='13' cpuset='13'/>
<vcpupin vcpu='14' cpuset='14'/>
<vcpupin vcpu='15' cpuset='15'/>
<vcpupin vcpu='16' cpuset='16'/>
<vcpupin vcpu='17' cpuset='17'/>
<vcpupin vcpu='18' cpuset='18'/>
<vcpupin vcpu='19' cpuset='19'/>
<vcpupin vcpu='20' cpuset='20'/>
<vcpupin vcpu='21' cpuset='21'/>
<vcpupin vcpu='22' cpuset='22'/>
<vcpupin vcpu='23' cpuset='23'/>
<vcpupin vcpu='24' cpuset='24'/>
<vcpupin vcpu='25' cpuset='25'/>
<vcpupin vcpu='26' cpuset='26'/>
<vcpupin vcpu='27' cpuset='27'/>
<vcpupin vcpu='28' cpuset='28'/>
<vcpupin vcpu='29' cpuset='29'/>
<vcpupin vcpu='30' cpuset='30'/>
<vcpupin vcpu='31' cpuset='31'/>
</cputune>
<resource>
<partition>/machine</partition>
</resource>
<sysinfo type='smbios'>
<bios>
<entry name='vendor'>PeerApp</entry>
</bios>
<system>
<entry name='manufacturer'>Dell</entry>
<entry name='product'>PowerEdge R730XD</entry>
<entry name='version'>Not</entry>
<entry name='serial'>BLHGG42</entry>
</system>
</sysinfo>
<os>
<type arch='x86_64' machine='pc-i440fx-rhel7.0.0'>hvm</type>
<boot dev='hd'/>
<bootmenu enable='yes'/>
<smbios mode='sysinfo'/>
</os>
<features>
<acpi/>
<apic/>
<pae/>
</features>
<cpu mode='host-passthrough'>
</cpu>
<clock offset='utc'/>
<on_poweroff>destroy</on_poweroff>
<on_reboot>restart</on_reboot>
<on_crash>restart</on_crash>
<devices>
<emulator>/usr/libexec/qemu-kvm</emulator>
<disk type='file' device='disk'>
<driver name='qemu' type='raw' cache='none'/>
<source file='/opt/ub.img'/>
<target dev='sda' bus='scsi'/>
<address type='drive' controller='0' bus='0' target='0' unit='0'/>
</disk>
<disk type='block' device='disk'>
<driver name='qemu' type='raw' cache='none' io='native'/>
<source dev='/dev/sdb'/>
<target dev='sdb' bus='scsi'/>
<address type='drive' controller='0' bus='0' target='0' unit='1'/>
</disk>
<disk type='block' device='disk'>
<driver name='qemu' type='raw' cache='none' io='native'/>
<source dev='/dev/sdc'/>
<target dev='sdc' bus='scsi'/>
<address type='drive' controller='0' bus='0' target='0' unit='2'/>
</disk>
<disk type='block' device='disk'>
<driver name='qemu' type='raw' cache='none' io='native'/>
<source dev='/dev/sdd'/>
<target dev='sdd' bus='scsi'/>
<address type='drive' controller='0' bus='0' target='0' unit='3'/>
</disk>
<disk type='block' device='disk'>
<driver name='qemu' type='raw' cache='none' io='native'/>
<source dev='/dev/sde'/>
<target dev='sde' bus='scsi'/>
<address type='drive' controller='0' bus='0' target='0' unit='4'/>
</disk>
<disk type='block' device='disk'>
<driver name='qemu' type='raw' cache='none' io='native'/>
<source dev='/dev/sdf'/>
<target dev='sdf' bus='scsi'/>
<address type='drive' controller='0' bus='0' target='0' unit='5'/>
</disk>
<disk type='block' device='disk'>
<driver name='qemu' type='raw' cache='none' io='native'/>
<source dev='/dev/sdg'/>
<target dev='sdg' bus='scsi'/>
<address type='drive' controller='0' bus='0' target='0' unit='6'/>
</disk>
<disk type='block' device='disk'>
<driver name='qemu' type='raw' cache='none' io='native'/>
<source dev='/dev/sdh'/>
<target dev='sdh' bus='scsi'/>
<address type='drive' controller='1' bus='0' target='0' unit='0'/>
</disk>
<disk type='block' device='disk'>
<driver name='qemu' type='raw' cache='none' io='native'/>
<source dev='/dev/sdi'/>
<target dev='sdi' bus='scsi'/>
<address type='drive' controller='1' bus='0' target='0' unit='1'/>
</disk>
<disk type='block' device='disk'>
<driver name='qemu' type='raw' cache='none' io='native'/>
<source dev='/dev/sdj'/>
<target dev='sdj' bus='scsi'/>
<address type='drive' controller='1' bus='0' target='0' unit='2'/>
</disk>
<disk type='block' device='disk'>
<driver name='qemu' type='raw' cache='none' io='native'/>
<source dev='/dev/sdk'/>
<target dev='sdk' bus='scsi'/>
<address type='drive' controller='1' bus='0' target='0' unit='3'/>
</disk>
<disk type='file' device='cdrom'>
<driver name='qemu' type='raw'/>
<source file='/opt/pa-unified.iso'/>
<target dev='hdc' bus='ide'/>
<readonly/>
<address type='drive' controller='0' bus='1' target='0' unit='0'/>
</disk>
<disk type='block' device='disk'>
<driver name='qemu' type='raw' cache='none' io='native'/>
<source dev='/dev/sdl'/>
<target dev='sdl' bus='virtio'/>
<address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x08' function='0x0'/>
</disk>
<controller type='usb' index='0'>
<address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x01' function='0x2'/>
</controller>
<controller type='pci' index='0' model='pci-root'/>
<controller type='ide' index='0'>
<address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x01' function='0x1'/>
</controller>
<controller type='virtio-serial' index='0'>
<address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x03' function='0x0'/>
</controller>
<controller type='scsi' index='0'>
<address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x06' function='0x0'/>
</controller>
<controller type='scsi' index='1'>
<address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x07' function='0x0'/>
</controller>
<interface type='direct'>
<mac address='52:54:00:33:75:9f'/>
<source dev='bond0' mode='vepa'/>
<model type='virtio'/>
<address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x09' function='0x0'/>
</interface>
<interface type='network'>
<mac address='52:54:00:7f:e3:20'/>
<source network='isolated'/>
<model type='virtio'/>
<address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x0a' function='0x0'/>
</interface>
<interface type='direct'>
<mac address='52:54:00:6f:17:f9'/>
<source dev='eno1' mode='vepa'/>
<model type='virtio'/>
<address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x0b' function='0x0'/>
</interface>
<interface type='direct'>
<mac address='52:54:00:db:17:5b'/>
<source dev='eno2' mode='vepa'/>
<model type='virtio'/>
<address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x0c' function='0x0'/>
</interface>
<serial type='pty'>
<target port='0'/>
</serial>
<console type='pty'>
<target type='serial' port='0'/>
</console>
<channel type='spicevmc'>
<target type='virtio' name='com.redhat.spice.0'/>
<address type='virtio-serial' controller='0' bus='0' port='1'/>
</channel>
<input type='mouse' bus='ps2'/>
<input type='keyboard' bus='ps2'/>
<graphics type='spice' autoport='yes' listen='127.0.0.1'>
<listen type='address' address='127.0.0.1'/>
</graphics>
<video>
<model type='qxl' ram='65536' vram='65536' vgamem='16384' heads='1'/>
<address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x02' function='0x0'/>
</video>
<hostdev mode='subsystem' type='pci' managed='yes'>
<source>
<address domain='0x0000' bus='0x81' slot='0x00' function='0x0'/>
</source>
<address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x0d' function='0x0'/>
</hostdev>
<hostdev mode='subsystem' type='pci' managed='yes'>
<source>
<address domain='0x0000' bus='0x81' slot='0x00' function='0x1'/>
</source>
<address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x0e' function='0x0'/>
</hostdev>
<hostdev mode='subsystem' type='pci' managed='yes'>
<source>
<address domain='0x0000' bus='0x82' slot='0x00' function='0x0'/>
</source>
<address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x0f' function='0x0'/>
</hostdev>
<hostdev mode='subsystem' type='pci' managed='yes'>
<source>
<address domain='0x0000' bus='0x82' slot='0x00' function='0x1'/>
</source>
<address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x10' function='0x0'/>
</hostdev>
<hostdev mode='subsystem' type='pci' managed='yes'>
<source>
<address domain='0x0000' bus='0x83' slot='0x00' function='0x0'/>
</source>
<address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x11' function='0x0'/>
</hostdev>
<hostdev mode='subsystem' type='pci' managed='yes'>
<source>
<address domain='0x0000' bus='0x83' slot='0x00' function='0x1'/>
</source>
<address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x12' function='0x0'/>
</hostdev>
<hostdev mode='subsystem' type='pci' managed='yes'>
<source>
<address domain='0x0000' bus='0x84' slot='0x00' function='0x0'/>
</source>
<address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x13' function='0x0'/>
</hostdev>
<hostdev mode='subsystem' type='pci' managed='yes'>
<source>
<address domain='0x0000' bus='0x84' slot='0x00' function='0x1'/>
</source>
<address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x14' function='0x0'/>
</hostdev>
<watchdog model='i6300esb' action='reset'>
<address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x04' function='0x0'/>
</watchdog>
<memballoon model='virtio'>
<address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x05' function='0x0'/>
</memballoon>
</devices>
</domain>
```

Comment: I found the command fro libguestfs

Comment: virt-filesystems -a /opt/ub.img

Comment: but i can't see the other disks for example /dev/sdc /dev/sdf

Answer (score 2):

You have to use a "loop device" to be able to mount the raw/qcow images. 
Sample commands:

```
mkdir -p /mnt/ubimage
losetup /dev/loop0 /opt/ub.img
kpartx -a /dev/loop0
mount /dev/mapper/loop0p1 /mnt/ubimage
```

If your VM has been installed with LVM. 
you need to apply additional steps:

```
vgscan
vgchange -ay
mount /dev/VolGroupName/LogVolName /mnt/ubimage
```

Links: [losetup](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/losetup.8.html), [kpartx](https://nfolamp.wordpress.com/2010/08/16/mounting-raw-image-files-and-kpartx/), [sample](http://alexeytorkhov.blogspot.com.tr/2009/09/mounting-raw-and-qcow2-vm-disk-images.html)